# How to set the terminal to open maximized

Tags: compiz, gnome-terminal

I want to tell compiz, metacity, the gnome-terminal or whoever is in charge to open the terminal window maximized by default.

How can I do that?

EDIT for the future: most of the answers were upvoted in older ubuntu versions, since 17.10 and on the most upvoted solutions do not work.

Answer (score 54):

Launch gnome-terminal as such:

```
gnome-terminal --window --maximize
```

Comment: It works with the shortcut in the menu bar but it doesn't if I lunch it via gnome-do :(

I'm accepting this answer anyway :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gnome-do depends on what's set in the gnome-terminal.desktop file.

Comment: this works when you launch the command from the terminal or something of the like, but it has no effect on the `.desktop` file on ubuntu 17.10+

Answer (score 39):

- Open a Terminal.
- From `Edit` menu select `Profile Preferences`.
- Tick `Use custom default terminal size` and enter a default size that is **too large** for the screen e.g. 240 columns and 100 rows.

Close, then open a new Terminal by clicking the icon (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>): the new terminal window should be maximised.

This answer is based upon advice I was given here:
[How to make terminal start maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138860/how-to-make-terminal-start-maximized)

Comment: I confirm this works in 12.04, and is probably the easiest solution (at least for people like me who always work with maximized windows) - thanks! My advice is to set the default columns and rows to just slightly more than what fills the screen, in order not to have problems in case you un-maximize the window.

Comment: If you temporarily need a small window, you can always un-maximize the window (double click on top) and click on `Terminal > 80x24`

Comment: This is the simplest way that works!

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but it makes it only almost maximized with a narrow margin on the right and the bottom. Even if I enter absurd 999 x 999 dimensions.

Answer (score 31):

If you want gnome-terminal to open fullscreen when you open it with Gnome Do or the Applications menu, put the following into a file named `gnome-terminal.desktop` and put that in `~/.local/share/applications`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=Use the command line
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal --window --maximize
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/index.html
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-terminal
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.32.0
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal
```

Then log out and log back to apply the changes.

Comment: It doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Actually I found it that [Terminal] disappear from my unity dash. What I realize instead copy above code (outdated on my U13.10) it's better to copy original file
`$ cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`
and then edit it changing
`Exec=gnome-terminal`
to 
`Exec=gnome-terminal --window --maximize`.

Logout then login again.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I saw the change take effect after closing all my Terminal windows and then relaunching it.  Not sure if that's what you meant by "log out and log back" but it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea to make it work with the Launcher and nautilus-open-terminal package?

Comment: `gnome-terminal --help-window-options`

Comment: As of ubuntu 17.10 it's not working.

Comment: Please consider updating this answer to advise copying the existing desktop file rather than creating a new one. I can't upvote this as it stands.

Answer (score 9):

## Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 LTS

Run `ccsm` (CompizConfig Settings Manager). Under Window Management enable Window Rules and open it, and in the Maximized field put `class=Gnome-terminal`. You may need to log out and log back in before the changes come into effect.

If you don't see Window Rules, then make sure you've got the `compiz-plugins` package installed.

You can do more. I use `(class=Gnome-terminal) | (class=Evince)`.

Comment: I needed to reboot after adding this rule for it to take effect.

Comment: doesn't work for me :-(. tried rebooting, logging in and out, grabbing the window class automatically (by clicking on the Terminal). I typically start my terminal from the sidebar or with Ctrl+Alt+T. In both cases it still starts with small size.

Answer (score 8):

### In Ubuntu 11.10 and up:

- Search > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > Add (+ button) >

  - Name: Launch Terminal Maximized
  - Command: `gnome-terminal --window --maximize`
- Click Apply
- Click on 'Disabled'
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: Do not use "Ubuntu 12" there are always 2 versions per year.

Comment: where is that Search menu item? (12.04)

Comment: Launch the 'System Settings' applet from Dash, and there's a search-box in the top-right corner of that applet. That's what I was referring to. 

BTW, I have been using the method described by @Craig above, and also the --maximmize option for scripting.

Comment: Thank you. Works without the `--window` option.

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer didn't work for me on fully updated Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, so I decided it was time for a more drastic approach. The solutions below are tested up to 16.04 LTS.

**My old solution**

1. Rename original `gnome-terminal` executable to
   `gnome-terminal-original`:

   ```
   cd /usr/bin
   sudo mv gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-original
   ```
2. Create a new file in `/usr/bin` named `gnome-terminal` with the
   following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/bin/gnome-terminal-original --maximize $@
   ```
3. Make it executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x gnome-terminal
   ```

Now no matter how I open the terminal, it always opens maximized. The only downside I see for this approach is that you have to repeat these steps every time you might update `gnome-terminal` with a new version via update manager or `apt-get upgrade`.

Note: the `$@` parameter means that all arguments that might get passed to `gnome-terminal` will still get passed to `gnome-terminal-original`, along with `--maximize` argument.

**A better solution**

1. Install "wmctrl":

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Add this line to the very end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

   ```
   wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
   ```
3. Repeat the second step for other user's `.bashrc` files if needed, for example, for "root" user (`/root/.bashrc`).

This solution will not affect the size of the terminal window initially, but rather maximize it shortly after it opens, usually in a matter of milliseconds. You can try moving the line you added in the second step to the beginning of `.bashrc` file, to make the terminal maximize even earlier.

Comment: This is first thing I would always do whenever I install/re-install Ubuntu. Works like a charm.

Comment: Why doesn't this approach work for `Open in terminal` context menu entry in Nautilus file manager?

Comment: @RobertOrzanna if this solution works for you in other situations, it's most likely that Nautilus runs a different terminal program (usually there's more than one installed). Try opening a new terminal while the one launched by Nautilus is running and do `ps aux` or `ps aux | grep term` to find out which executables are running. Or, try switching the arguments on the second line in the script like so: `$@ --maximize`.

Comment: Thanks @Brane! Please see [this](http://i.imgur.com/bmnAvLi.gif) gif animation.

Comment: @RobertOrzanna Wow, thanks for your effort in describing the problem. I never paid much attention to `gnome-terminal`, but as it turns out, the original `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` itself is a launcher for `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server`. So, other programs can start `gnome-terminal-server` directly, in which case my first solution won't work. But, don't worry, I found another stupid trick that will work even in those cases (see my updated answer above) :)

Comment: Thanks, @Brane! Your updated answer does work excellently! This only affects `gnome-terminal` windows or all windows in general?

Comment: @RobertOrzanna You're welcome, I'm glad it works for you. The updated solution should affect all terminal windows, not just `gnome-terminal` - try opening `uxterm` for example. To put it more accurately, it should affect all applications that start `bash` or `dash` in a regular window and load your `.bashrc` file. It's possible however, to limit the affected applications. If anyone needs that, let me know and I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @Brane how would I auto-maximise all windows?

Comment: @RobertOrzanna Take a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized - basically install "maximus" and make it run at startup.

Comment: I like your old solution the best; simple and effective.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
gnome-terminal --full-screen
```

You could create a shortcut on your desktop or panel to this command.

Comment: There's a difference between full screen and maximized though.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the terminal to open full size on screen, use the GUI method of changing the default size through current profile preferences dialog appropriately. To do so, simply follow these steps:

- Open a terminal
- Choose Edit
- In the General tab, check "Use custom default terminal size"
- You need to adjust these values so that they fit your screen 
  by simple trial and error

The column setting is 128 for me. You should set the values that best suit you.

Comment: Making the window the same size as the desktop doesn't make it *maximized*

Comment: @DoR I know but i still consider it as an option and a rather good and easy one at that because it will work even if he uses gnome-do and this is for a newbie who may have the same question he might find this thread and he deserves to have all options shown as he cannot ask a duplicate question and suppose he dosen't want it fully maximized or wants to use gnome-do or any new launcher this option survives...

Answer (score 1):

Just add a custom shortcut.

Go to *Settings* > *Devices* >  *Keyboard*,  scroll down to the end of the list and click on the `+` to add your shortcut.

Give it a name and in the command section type `gnome-terminal --maximize` and add your preferred keyboard shortcut combination.

Answer (score 0):

In QTerminal, you can maximize the window and then close the terminal by the "exit" command. When you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> again it will automatically open maximized.

This can be applied to any size, just set the size you want, "exit" and then open again.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably modify your shortcuts to use the maximize one so that it always starts that way.

The easiest way of doing so is to locate your application (in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`) and to modify your `.desktop` file.

In that `.desktop` file, you will see the line that starts  with `Exec=...`. To start `gnome-terminal` maximized, all you need to do is to add `--start-maximized` to the end of the command.

Comment: Can you provide any information about *how* to do this?