# How to configure my system so that all windows start maximized?

Tags: window-manager

Every time I open a terminal or an application like Inkscape I have to click the maximize button because by default they open in a small size. Is there a way I can configure my system so that whenever a new program opens, it uses the whole screen?

Here is an example of how small the window of Inkscape is when it opens:

[image: example of how inkscape (and any other application) opens small]

Comment: if you maximise the window, and close the program and open it the next time, the size isnt remembered?

Comment: @Kaustubh, that is not the case for all applications.

Comment: it is certainly not the case for the Terminal and Inkscape

Comment: You can set it for the Terminal tho.

Comment: how can i set it for the Terminal? in any case, i want to set it for all applications

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Install [maximus [image: Install maximus]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/maximus) from the Software Center or from the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install maximus
```

Then run this command from the Terminal:

```
maximus
```

All the new windows will be maximized with that.

Finally, just like in the screen shot at the 5th point in [Isaiah's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/940252), add an entry in the Startup Applications. The name can be whatever you want, and the command will be simply `maximus`.

Comment: I installed it. It is great. Thanks a lot for the recommendation! However, it does not do what I need. It maximizes existing windows. I want it to maximize the windows of the applications I will open. Not the ones I already have opened.

Comment: @andresmh, did you try opening anything while `maximus` is running? If you rebooted the system, unless you add an entry at Startup Applications, it won't run.

Comment: you're totally right. I put maximus so it starts at boot time and it now works great. Thanks!

Comment: Glad my bits of knowledge regarding Ubuntu could be helpful!

Comment: Can Maximus exclude some windows? For example, I don't want [Vokoscreen](http://i.imgur.com/F3aGC9k.png) to be maximised.

Comment: @RobertOrzanna, I'm sorry, according to its manpages, there's no option to let it be exclusive or inclusive.

Comment: Maybe the `devlispie` mentioned in the next answer can help.

Comment: @Oxwivi thank you! I will take a look at Devilspie.

Comment: Maximus opens all windows in fullscreen mode. This is a similar, but not the same, of maximized mode. This should be explained in the answers.

Comment: This works on mint as well for cinnamon desktop. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 23):

1. Install devilspie.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install devilspie
   ```

   [Devil's Pie](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie) is:

   > A window-matching utility, inspired by Sawfish's "Matched Windows" option and the lack of the functionality in Metacity. Metacity lacking window matching is not a bad thing — Metacity is a lean window manager, and window matching does not have to be a window manager task.
   >
   > Devil's Pie can be configured to detect windows as they are created, and match the window to a set of rules. If the window matches the rules, it can perform a series of actions on that window. For example, I can make all windows created by X-Chat appear on all workspaces, and the main Gkrellm1 window does not appear in the pager or task list.
2. Create the directory `~/.devilspie` if it doesn't already exist:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.devilspie
   ```
3. Now we'll create the script that will maximize all windows:

   ```
   gedit ~/.devilspie/maximize.ds
   ```

   Paste the following code into `maximize.ds`:

   ```
   (begin
       (maximize)(focus)
   )
   ```

   [image]
4. Run the following command from a terminal:

   ```
   devilspie
   ```
5. All your windows should now be maximized. Now add `devilspie` to your *Startup Applications* so you won't have to run it manually every time you login:

   - *System ➜ Preferences ➜ Startup Applications*
   - Click *Add* and enter `Devil's Pie` for the *Name* and `/usr/bin/devilspie` for the *Command*.
   - Click *Add* and close *Startup Applications*.

   [image]

Comment: This looks like a solution but I was hoping something that didn't have to run an extra process. I wonder how cpu/memory intensive this is. I was hoping I would just have to change some existing config files.

Comment: @andresmh `devilspie` is idle except when you open a new window, it is **very** light on system resources.

Comment: How can I make it that only certain applications are affected from this?

Answer (score 10):

1. Install [CompizConfig-Settings-Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager),
2. Open <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
3. Go to "Place Windows"
   [image]
4. Select "Fixed Window Placement" > "Window with fixed placement mode" > "New"
   [image]
5. At "Windows" paste: `type=Normal`
6. At "Mode" select: "Maximize".
   [image]

Answer (score 9):

For regular Inkscape users which get annoyed by that problem there is a solution.

1. Start up Inkscape.
2. Maximize it.
3. Go to *File ➜ Inkscape Preferences ➜ Windows*.
4. Select *Remember and use last window's geometry*.

   [image]
5. Always close it in maximized mode.

Now every time you fire up Inkscape it will load up with its saved geometry.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Compiz, go to "Window Management" (under categories or scroll down in the main window) and do the next:

*DO NOT ENABLE WINDOWS RULES YET!*

1. Open "Window Rules".
2. In the "Matches" tab, find
   "Maximized" and write `class=`
3. Then enable Window Rules. (Check box on left or in main window)

Now, all your windows (and I mean: ALL) will ALWAYS open Maximized.

***WARNING!*** This will also include dialogs, normal windows, and every window will act as you requested. This was your wish, right? always be sure that you really wish what you wish. :)

You can also do several things, which includes (but not limited to):

- Enabling a single program to open
  maximized, by clicking the "plus"
  icon in the right side and pressing
  the "Grab" button in order to choose
  the window of the program. which
  should be running in order to do
  this, you can also write the title,
  role, type, name, etc.
- Exclude a single program to not
  observe this feature by doing the
  last steps and making sure you enable
  the "Invert" button in the dialog
  box.
- Use other windows rules, like:

**Skip taskbar:** in order to the windows won't appear in the task bar.
**Skip pager:** this way the windows won't appear when you change an application by using [Alt][Tab] or [Super][Tab]
**Above:** the windows will always stay above the rest of the windows keeping the focus always.
**Below:** Useful when you wish an application, like the terminal, to be as "embedded" into the desktop.
**Fullscreen:** doesn't need explanation.
**Non movable, Non resizable, Non minimizable, Non maxibizable, Non closable, Non focus:** does what it says.

A screenshot is placed here for you to see this plugin's in action:

[image]

HOW TO OVERRIDE THIS WINDOWS BEHAVIOUR:

You will be in the need to gain access to compiz, and disable the "Window Rules" plugin.

If you did something that don't allow you to see compiz, (something like: making a window to stay "above" of the other and maximized or fullscreen), open a terminal and disable compiz by running: `metacity --replace`.

Good Luck!

*The uppercase are just to emphasize important text. Can be edited and changed by anyone if needed. Thank you.*

Answer (score 1):

I you are using compiz you can also:

1. **install ccsm** from software center or sudo apt-get install ccsm. It's a compiz configurator
2. **launch it** from dash or from terminal
3. select **windows placement** and in the **general** tab change the **positioning mode** to **maximized**

I found this works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

What concerns Gnome 3, I can say that usually when you close any application, it remembers the size, and next time, when it opens again.

So all you need to do is to maximize it before exit.