# How do I make Firefox start always maximized?

Tags: gnome, firefox

I am setting up Ubuntu with gnome for my grandma. How can I make firefox start ALWAYS maximized.

Comment: See the different answers of http://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized

Comment: "class=Firefox"
Disadvantage: you can't un-maximize it.
. . . So the **answer** is to enter "class=Firefox", then open firefox, then close firefox, then remove the "class=Firefox". Now it will open up maximized, and you can un-maximize it any time you want.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to achieve this with a python script. The script requires python-wnck and python-gtk to be installed in order to work, although I think these are installed by default anyway.

Copy and paste this into a text editor and save it somewhere (eg ~/.maximised-firefox.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wnck
import gtk
import subprocess
import time

firefox = subprocess.Popen(["firefox"])

b = True
while b:
    screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration()
    windows = screen.get_windows()
    for w in windows:
        if w.get_pid() == firefox.pid:
            w.maximize()
            b = False
    time.sleep(1)


firefox.wait()
```

Then make this executable and copy to a system wide location by opening a terminal and running:

```
chmod +x ~/.maximised-firefox.py
sudo cp ~/.maximised-firefox.py /usr/bin/maximised-firefox
```

You can then, using your grandma's profile, edit the menus using the menu editor. You can get to this from the right click menu of the menu or by running `alacarte`.

Then edit the firefox item and set the command to `maximised-firefox`.

[image: menu editor]

Comment: If you're not using the traditional menu (for example, if you're using the Unity Dash and Launcher), will you need to change the command for those Firefox launchers separately?

Comment: No because the traditional menu, menu editor and the Unity dash all use gmenu as their backend.

Comment: Interesting solution, I had to `sudo apt-get install python-wnck` on Xubuntu 14.04 to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using [Compiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz), you can force an application window to have certain characteristics (e.g. fullscreen, always maximized) by tweaking some settings:

1. Install [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) [image: Install CompizConfig]

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open it and go to the Window Rules section.
3. In the `Maximized` text box, enter `name=Navigator`
4. Finally, enable the Window Rules plugin (checkbox on the left).

[image: screenshot of the Window Rules settings for Compiz]

This will cause Firefox to always start maximized.  As a potentially negative side effect, it will also make it impossible to un-maximize Firefox.

Comment: `class=Firefox` also works.

Comment: @dv3500ea that's a lot more logical than `name=Navigator`, but I don't think I'll update my answer because I'm too lazy to take a new screenshot. :)

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this article](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/24/firefox-not-remembering-the-last-window-size-this-may-fix-it/), it may be because of **resistFingerprinting** config.

1. Load *about:config* in the Firefox address bar.
2. Confirm that you will be careful if the warning message is displayed.
3. Search for *privacy.resistFingerprinting* If the preference is set to True, the extra fingerprinting protection is enabled, if it is set to False, it is disabled.
4. If true, set it to false and restart Firefox.

Hope it helps.