# How to configure Unity/Compiz in 12.04 so that Update Manager opens maximized w/screen bigger than 1024×600?

Tags: unity, compiz, update-manager

[In Precise, window auto-maximize is disabled on monitors with a resolution above 1024 × 600](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/797808) [1]. I have a bigger resolution, but I prefer maximized windows anyway. I want Update Manager to start maximized.

What I've tried so far:

1. In Compiz Config Settings Manager, I have Place Windows activated and 'Windows with fixed placement mode' has windows matching the rule "(name=gnome-terminal) | (name=update-manager)" set to 'Maximize'. With this, Gnome Terminal starts maximized, Update Manager does not.
2. In Compiz Config Settings Manager, I have set a [Window Rules](https://askubuntu.com/a/53657/34756) [2] rule to match "name=update-manager". Irregardless of any rules set or not, activating Window Rules results in not being able to bring out Unity Launcher anymore, Alt+Tab window switching becoming slow or nonfunctional entirely and the screen sporadically freezing completely. Not a viable option apparently.
3. I've installed [Maximus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized) [3] and started it. Update Manager ignores it (or vice versa).

I've not tried devilspie and would prefer not to. Having to configure something external for this would seem stupidly redundant with (the no-brainer) Maximus and all these Compiz options already available. I just can't seem to make them work.

**Edit:** For some time now, I've had the 2nd solution above (Window Rules) in use, and the Unity-related problems have no longer manifested themselves; apparently the related bugs have been fixed (although I've only found [one expired bug from Launchpad that seems to describe the issues I had](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/786332#yui_3_10_3_1_1393236486196_51) [4]). I'm therefore closing this.

- [1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/797808
- [2] https://askubuntu.com/a/53657/34756
- [3] [How to configure my system so that all windows start maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized)
- [4] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/786332#yui_3_10_3_1_1393236486196_51

Comment: Never got Compiz to do the job, so I'm closing this as Eric suggested. FWIW, this devilspie script seems to work:

(if (matches (application_name) "^update-manager$") (maximize))

Comment: Uh, except there's no "abandoned" alternative in the closing alternatives, and the question is still valid.

Comment: Abandoned questions are usually closed as "Too localized", but if you're still looking for an answer there's no need for closing it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice Eric. I do intend to post here if I do come across a solution, so I'll keep this open for now. Software updater in current releases looks different, so I'll probably close this in any case once the next LTS comes around and I've upgraded.

Comment: Have this ever got solved?

Comment: As I explained in the Edit paragraph I added, the "solution" was more of the problem as I presented it going away (through related bugs getting fixed) than finding a path of steps to take.