# How can I start a program minimised, and restore maximised?

Tags: window-manager, restore, window-management, minimize, maximized

There are various options to [start a program minimised](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20989), or to [start a program maximised](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826) and they work well, but I'm always looking for new challenges.

If I start a program minimised using the Devil's Pie method, and then click on it in the launcher, it restores to its regular size. Instead, I would like it to restore to a maximised state.

In other words, I want it to act as though it had started maximised, and then been minimised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a minimized maximized window using Python:

```
import wnck
import gtk
import subprocess
import time

chrome = subprocess.Popen(["google-chrome"])

b = True
while b:
    screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
    while gtk.events_pending():
        gtk.main_iteration()
    windows = screen.get_windows()
    for w in windows:
        if w.get_pid() == chrome.pid:
            w.maximize()
            w.minimize()
            b = False
    time.sleep(1)


chrome.wait()
```

`google-chrome` in this case will maximize then minimize. After this you just create a .desktop that can launch the script like the example shown below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Application Name
Comment=Application Comment
Exec=python /exact/path/to/python/script.py
Icon=icon
Categories=valid categories;
```

Make sure to set the desktop as a executable file or it will not function.

The script should be edited on line 6 where *google-chrome* should be replaced with whatever command you wish to execute. If the program have parameters they can be passed as following: `"google-chrome", "para1", "para2"`.

Cred to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53646/how-do-i-make-firefox-start-always-maximized) for the python script (changed to chrome in my testing).

Comment: Interesting solution, I had to `sudo apt-get install python-wnck` on Xubuntu 14.04 to get it to work.

Comment: Oh, was already installed on Ubuntu :)