# How can I start all applications maximised?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure my system so that all windows start maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized)

Is it possible to start any and all applications maximised?