# How do I set all applications to start unfocused or minimized?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, focus

Isn't there a way to force all apps to start up minimized or make them load in the background so they won't be opened on top of the window that I'm working on, besides making the window to be always on top?

I notice lot of similar questions like this one get blindly answered with solution that involves fiddling with window rules setting in `CompizConfig > General > Focus & Raise Behavior` but that actually does nothing to prevent this kind of focus stealing.

Comment: Different applications use different flags to start minimized, and not all have this functionality. You have to look at each man page individually and hand-edit each .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`. Are you willing to do this? If not, try using Devilspie. Some good instructions are [here in this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/27826/12864), which is the exact opposite of yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check GDevilSpie from the Software Center, here is a tutorial
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/how-to-start-applications-minimized.html

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Why we can't have something like this built into Compiz by default?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using workspaces (called viewports in Compiz), you can use [devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/) to open applications maximalized in a different workspace. It uses lua as its scripting language so it is quite powerfull. It does not work that well with viewports as they are technically only a section of one big workspace, so some workarounds and external tools are needed. This is a script I use to place pidign conversation to viewport 3,3 (third from the top and left) of my fullHD screen (1920×1080):

```
-- a helper function to capture string from external command output
function os.capture(cmd, raw)
  local f = assert(io.popen(cmd, 'r'))
  local s = assert(f:read('*a'))
  f:close()
  if raw then return s end
  s = string.gsub(s, '^%s+', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '%s+$', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '[\n\r]+', ' ')
  return s
end


if (get_window_class()=="Pidgin" and get_window_role()=="conversation") then
    -- get the current viewport
    vp = os.capture("xprop -root |grep '_NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT(CARDINAL) = ' |cut -d ' ' -f 3-4 |tr -d ','")
    -- unfortunately, the below does not work due to a bug in xdotool
    -- vp = os.capture("xdotool get_desktop_viewport")
    -- set_window_geomtery is relative to current position, it seems, so go to the left and top most vieport
    os.execute("xdotool set_desktop_viewport 0 0")
    -- set the window maximized and to viewport 3,3
    set_window_geometry(3930,2250,650,950)
    maximize()
    -- now go to the original viewport
    os.execute("xdotool set_desktop_viewport " .. vp)
end
```

The script depends on `x11-utils` and `xdotool`. It results in a very short flicker when the app is open. It can be eliminated by using CCSM and setting Wall sliding duration time to zero milliseconds.