# Setting Screen Size on Chrome Kiosk

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, kiosk

I'm trying to make a kiosk machine working with Ubuntu(13.04) and i'm done some parts.Chrome is openning on kiosk mode but i don't know how i set the chrome with my screensize.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--window-size=<WIDTH>,<HEIGHT>` and `--app-shell-host-window-size=<WIDTH>x<HEIGHT>` arguments (make sure to get the separators correct).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to configure Chromium to start with a particular window size directly.  However, you can do this via your window manager configuration, or using a window manipulation tool such as maximus.

For example, our [kiosk OS](http://www.rapidrollout.com/) (which is based on Ubuntu) has an option to open all application windows full screen.  To do this, we use the Compiz "Window Rules" plugin and set the "Maximized" window match to "type=Normal | type=Unknown" (this makes non-application windows such as dialogs open normally).  We also disable decorations for these windows using the "Decoration" plugin.

There's more than one way to do it, though.  For example, you could use the [Maximus](http://lifehacker.com/5609147/use-maximus-to-go-full+screen-in-ubuntu) program.  This is a separate utility that runs alongside the window manager and maximizes application windows when they are created.

I suggest reading through some of the answers to the question "[How to configure my system so that all windows start maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized)", one of which includes more detailed instructions for configuring Compiz as I've described here.

Of course, if you used our free [web-based configuration tool](http://www.rapidrollout.com/workbench/) this would just take a click to configure. ;)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ForestBond but my trouble is different.I forgot to say i want to only chrome on my window.Cus i disabled unity launcher like [here](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/06/how-to-disable-unity-launcher-and-use.html). It was working before but when i disabled it, Chrome is not working as fullscreen.

Comment: ccsm "window rules" "size rules" worked thanks!