# How can I start Pidgin maximised if maximus doesn't do it?

Tags: pidgin, maximized

I use [maximus [image: Install maximus]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/maximus) to force applications to open in a maximized window, as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/27836/7146). [1] However, Pidgin message windows are not affected. When I start Pidgin, my buddy list doesn't appear [2] and my automatic group chats start, but they appear in the top left of the screen, not maximized.

How can I get Pidgin chat windows to start maximized? [3] Can I add/modify [the Pidgin gtkrc file](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#WhatisagtkrcfileandwherecanIfindit)?

[1] I found it the simplest reliable solution of those given. It didn't seem to work 100% in 12.04, but targets 99% of windows in 13.10.

[2] By choice. If I do allow it to appear on startup, **it** will appear maximized.

[3] I'd prefer not to switch to another maximizer, unless it is as trivial to install. Devil's Pie, while very flexible, requires configuration. As a last resort, I considered installing DP just to make a Pidgin rule.