# HDMI colour issue with Ubuntu - where to start?

Tags: hdmi, colors, color-management

I have two PCs using ***exactly the same hardware***. They come with windows preinstalled by the supplier.

I've removed windows and installed Ubuntu on one of the devices, and am experiencing two problems:

- When connected to some TVs the image overscans, i.e. parts of the image are missing from around the edge of the screen, as if the image is 'zoomed in' slightly.
- The colours on the image are very dark.

With the windows version, using the same TV, neither of the above problems exist.

Additionally, when we use a (more expensive!) Samsung TV, these issues don't occur even with the Ubuntu device - I think it's a bit smarter and is detecting the best settings based on the output.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Could it be a driver issue? What information (other than the image itself) is passed to the TV via HDMI?

**EDIT**

I've resolved the overscan issue using the TV's settings - switching the TV into 'PC' mode does the trick for that.

The image can't really be corrected via the TV's brightness/contrast settings - if I put the brightness up, blacks become light grey. Furthermore, I need this pc to work reliably on different TVs, without customising their colour settings each time. The fact that the colours are fine on windows suggests this is likely either a driver or a config issue to me.

The devices uses built in Intel graphics from an Intel Celeron N3350 processor.

Comment: For your overscan issue, simply take your TV remote and go to picture settings. Find an option like zoom, or very similar, adjust this setting until it fits. Likly you can do the same for the colour. If it did not work, please provide more detail on your GPU.

Comment: Thanks @MarkKirby - I found a setting on the TV to change the picture mode to 'PC' which fixed the size. I've updated with more info re: colour.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, same issue drove me mad. IDK a lot about colour profiles but the documentation is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-gettingprofiles.html and in `settings >> colour` you can manipulate the profiles, that is the best I have.