# Ubuntu 18.04 configure vlc always on top

Tags: vlc, window, gnome-shell, window-management

Ubuntu 18.04 with Cinnamon desktop.

1. VLC option View / Always on top doesn't work.
2. Right click on window title + Always on Top does work, but only for the current video

The first item is likely due to a bug in either VLC or GTK.

I'd like to configure VLC to always be on top when playing, without
having to click on the frame title each time I open a video. Any
answer to work around the bug in item 1, or to automate the workaround
in item 2 is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the first with `devilspie` or its GUI counterpart `gdevilspie`. You may refer to [this detailed answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/27833/) by [@Isaiah](https://askubuntu.com/users/114/isaiah) to learn more about how to use `devilspie`.

Once you're done setting up `devilspie`, add the following rule.

```
(if 
  (is (window_class) "vlc")
    (begin
        (above)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 8):

I found an easy way to activate it, via Ubuntu, not VLC.
According to [maketecheasier](https://www.maketecheasier.com/keyboard-shortcut-for-always-on-top-ubuntu) and verified by myself on Ubuntu 20:

```
Click on VLC window
Press ALT + Space
Select "Always on top" from the menu
```

Comment: You just made my day!

Comment: works in Ubuntu 22.04 too

Comment: Worked for me too. I was in trouble. Using Ubuntu 20.04.