# CompizConfig and gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, compiz, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to set the terminal to open maximized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158/how-to-set-the-terminal-to-open-maximized)

Place Windows > Fixed Window Placement > fixed placement mode

I have added

> Window class=Gnome-terminal
>
> Mode = Maximize

but when I open new gnome terminal from console its not Maximize. I also tried by title and it doesn't work.

I cannot restart my computer, maybe I need to restart Compiz?